# error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'UnityEvent' could not be found

Tags: c#

```
using UnityEngine.EventSystems;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Eventer : MonoBehaviour
{
    public UnityEvent onMouceClicked;

    void Update()
    {
        if (input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
        {
            OnMouceClicked?.Invoke();
        }    
    }
}
```

what did i do wrong? i just want to learn c# and watch video, making all like in video, but that error, i tried everything i know, nothing works

Comment: Pay attention not only to some fancy Youtube videos, but also to the [official documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/). The documentation for `UnityEvent` will tell you that the namespace in which this class resides is UnityEngine.Events.

Comment: Add `using UnityEngine.Events;` to your using statements

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

It should be `UnityEngine.Events`

Comment: This answer is in the "low quality answers queue" and **may** be voted for deletion. I suggest you try to expand the content detail to avoid that happening.